# Is there any possible to communicate with C#.Net server and iOS client using UDP sockets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sockets, udp

I am doing IP Messenger demo for iOS and I have idea about objective-c ans I don't know about C#.net. And the server was developed in C#.net and client have to develope in objective-c. Is there any possible to this type of demos. And I have tried some demos which are able to send onle text but not files(images). I have tried this demo[CocoaUDPAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).Can any one help me how to send image ?

```
 NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1:55:%@:IPhone:2097184:Hello\0 0:down-arrow.png:219:14de76bd790:1:\a",deviceInfo.name];
    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [asyncUDPSocket sendData:data withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
//219 is length of image. 14de76bd790 is last modified 
//of image both are in Hexadecimal. 2097184 is command number to send image file.
```

Comment: I didn't understand. I have to convert image to base64 encoding ?

Comment: I understand you have something ready to send strings. You can convert binary to a string by base64 encoding.  If that's not what you want, the obvious is to implement a solution that does binary transfer. But you will not get the out of the box solution for that on SO